# how do I close a server in socket.io 1.0?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

There are dupes of this, but they are for a previous version of the library. It seems that the code has changed.

I'm instantianting a socket like so:

```
this.socketLib || (this.socketLib = require('socket.io'));
this.socket = this.socketLib.listen(this.port);
```

Elsewhere in the object, I have a close function. I've tried the following to close the socket:

```
this.socket.close() # TypeError: Object #<Server> has no method 'close'
this.socket.server.close() #  TypeError: Object #<Server> has no method 'close'
this.socket.server.disconnect() #  TypeError: Cannot call method 'disconnect' of undefined
this.socket.disconnect() # TypeError: Object #<Server> has no method 'disconnect'
this.socket.io.engine.close() # TypeError: Cannot read property 'engine' of undefined
```

There are occurrences of `disconnect` in the codebase, but they are for the client it seems: ([link](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/search?q=disconnect&ref=cmdform)). Same thing for `close`, basically. Or I'm not seeing it.

I've debugged and poked around in the objects and not found anything that closes the server.

How do I close the socket server in the new codebase? I need to shut it down for integration testing (1st test run passes, 2nd run gets `EADDRINUSE` error). I'm trying to write a close function that I can run in my `after` function in mocha. My tests pass if I run them without `--watch`. It's just the multiple successive runs that are failing.

Comment: It looks like 1.0 is still missing a lot of features from the previous versions.

Comment: @dystroy ouch, wonder why? think there's a better alternative?

Comment: I don't know. For now I'm waiting to see how it turns in the next days or weeks. I froze the migration in my applications until it's clearer.

Comment: I just downgraded to 0.9. I'll submit an issue for this.

Comment: Submitted as issue (this should be answered by the docs): https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/1559

Comment: @jcollum Did you see my answer? Don't know if that is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps :-)

```
socket.conn.close ();
```

If you do this, you get an infinite number of `"a user connected"`

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.conn.close ();

        ....
});
```

Comment: I'll take a look in the future. For now, I've downgraded to Socket IO 0.9.